# iOS bluetooth scan devices failed after first time connection disconnected

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I tried to connect to a peripheral device and was able to scan and connect to it successfully for the first time, but after disconnecting, I couldn't find the device again. However, the nRF Connect app can still scan and find the device after the connection is disconnected. I also tried other apps, but they both cannot scan it after being disconnected.
If I restart my iPhone, it can be scanned again. turn on/off Bluetooth button in settings is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling `.cancelPeripheralConnection` in order to "disconnect." That does not promise that it will immediately disconnect. The OS may maintain the connection. Peripherals generally do not advertise when they're connected, so you won't see it. Toggling Bluetooth briefly may or may not drop a connection (it depends on how long it's off).

You should use [`CBCentralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1518924-retrieveconnectedperipherals) to find peripherals that are already connected when you try to scan.

Comment: I tried these functions `CBCentralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)  and CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers:)  `,  both return an empty array in my case. And when I  called the  `.cancelPeripheralConnection` ,  peripherals logs shows that the device already disconnect.

Comment: And do device logs show that it starts advertising again? Did you stop scanning and re-start scanning? (CBCentralManager automatically removes duplicates from scanned results by default.)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  We finally find the problem,  It's because of the difference in peripheral name between `peripheral.name` and  'kCBAdvDataLocalName' in advertisementData. Hardware team change it to same, the problem gone